# Check for key exists in the Aerospike database

Tags: php, aerospike

Could you please explain why the `Aerospike::exists` method throws **Fatal Error**:

**Code**:

```
$aerospike = new Aerospike(
    [
        'hosts' => [
            ['addr' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => 3000]
        ],
        'shm' => [],
    ],
    false,
    []
);

$bins = ['value' => 99];
$akey = $aerospike->initKey('test', 'cache', 'test-data');

$putStatus = $aerospike->put(
    $akey,
    $bins,
    0,
    [Aerospike::OPT_POLICY_KEY => Aerospike::POLICY_KEY_SEND]
);
var_dump($putStatus); // Aerospike::OK here

$deleteStatus = $aerospike->remove($akey);
var_dump($deleteStatus); // Aerospike::OK here

$existsStatus = $aerospike->exists($akey, $metadata); // Fatal error
```

**Environment**:

- Ubuntu 16.04.1
- PHP 7.0.13
- Arospike PHP Cient 3.4.13
- Aerospike Docker Image (Server): `aerospike:3.10.1`

**Test**:

```
$ php aerospike.php
/tmp/aerospike.php:24:
int(0)
/tmp/aerospike.php:27:
int(0)
PHP Fatal error:  Aerospike::exists(): exists/getMetadata: 
    unable to fetch the record in /tmp/aerospike.php on line 29
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /tmp/aerospike.php:0
PHP   2. Aerospike->exists() /tmp/aerospike.php:29
```

I found in [`src/aerospike/aerospike_record_operations.c`](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-php/blob/master/src/aerospike/aerospike_record_operations.c#L1450):

```
if (AEROSPIKE_OK != (status = aerospike_record_operations_exists(as_object_p, &as_key_for_put_record, error_p, metadata_p, options_p TSRMLS_CC)))
{
    DEBUG_PHP_EXT_ERROR("exists/getMetadata: unable to fetch the record");
    goto exit;
}
```

and in [`src/aerospike/aerospike_common.h`](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-php/blob/master/src/aerospike/aerospike_common.h#L476):

```
#define DEBUG_PHP_EXT_ERROR(args...) DEBUG_PHP_EXT_COMPARE_LEVEL(AS_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, E_ERROR, args)

#define DEBUG_PHP_EXT_COMPARE_LEVEL(log_level, php_log_level, args...)            \
do {                                                                              \
    if (!(((as_log_level) PHP_EXT_AS_LOG_LEVEL_OFF) == php_log_level_set))        \
        if (php_log_level_set >= log_level) {                                     \
            php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, php_log_level, args);                \
            aerospike_helper_log_callback((log_level | 0x08), __func__ TSRMLS_CC, \
                    __FILE__, __LINE__, ##args);                                  \
        }                                                                         \
} while(0)
```

I checked [the documentation](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-php/blob/master/doc/aerospike_exists.md) but found no hint of how this can be fixed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by compiling the php client with the following flags:

```
CFLAGS="-std=gnu99 -g -D__AEROSPIKE_PHP_CLIENT_LOG_LEVEL__=PHP_EXT_AS_LOG_LEVEL_OFF"
```